# Dados da base de dados para página web

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados

Necessitava de ajuda pois queria mandar os dados da minha base de dados para a página web

CAMPOS BASE DADOS: `Id_Produto`, `NomeProduto`, `PrecoProduto`,`DescricaoProduto`, `QuantidadeProduto`, `CategoriaProduto` -

NOME TABELA: `produtos`

A página que estou a criar é em php para poder ter acesso às informações da base de dados.

Mas não consigo fazer o código

estou a usar `

```
      mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pap') or die (mysqli_error ());



$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM produtos";

$rs = mysqli_query($strSQL);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {

echo $row['NomeProduto'] . "<br />";
echo $row['DescricaoProduto'] . "<br />";

  }

// Encerra a conexão
mysqli_close();  ?>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```html
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pap') or die (mysqli_error ());



$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM produtos";

$rs = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
echo" ".$row['NomeProduto']."";
echo" ".$row['DescricaoProduto']."";
  }

// Encerra a conexão
mysqli_close();  ?>
```

Comment: não aparecem os dados da base de dados, mas sim isto : ("; echo $row['DescricaoProduto'] . "
"; } // Encerra a conexão mysqli_close(); ?>)

Comment: @JoséGomes tente agora

Comment: continua a dar o mesmo erro

Comment: tenta agora @JoséGomes

Comment: já está a mandar os dados , mas fica com este icones  --> � e da um erro ainda 'Warning: mysqli_close() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\pagina_produto.php on line 459' que tem o seguinte código - mysqli_close();  ?>

Comment: apaga o mysqli_close(); não é necessário ;
deixa so ?>

Comment: e quanto aos pontos de ? sabe como resolver?

Comment: adiciona isto lá no inicio do codigo, asseguir ao <html> dentro do <head>   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

Comment: já tinha isso e não funciona

Comment: e se for so assim:      <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: tambem nao funciona